# Inconsistent Gaussian distributions for subsets of data - Python

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, contour, kernel-density

I am trying to plot a simple density distribution for some data. I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv('des_y3.csv)
```

Which I obtain its density as:

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
# Extract x and y
x = df['column_1'].to_numpy()
y = df['column_2'].to_numpy()
xx, yy = np.mgrid[min(x):max(x):100j, min(y):max(y):100j]

positions = np.vstack([xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([x, y])
kernel = st.gaussian_kde(values)
f_1 = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, xx.shape)
```

To this point, everything works well. The problem is when I try with a subset of the data, say, applying a condition

```
x = df['column_1'][df['column_3'] == 'E'].to_numpy()
y = df['column_2'][df['column_3'] == 'E'].to_numpy()
xx, yy = np.mgrid[min(x):max(x):100j, min(y):max(y):100j]

positions = np.vstack([xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([x, y])
kernel = st.gaussian_kde(values)
f_2 = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, xx.shape)
```

Now, my densities are inconsistent between the original set and the subset. I get larger values in f_2 than f_1, when the subset is a portion with very few values. How can I make it so the densities of the subsets are consistent with the original data?

If I plot the set vs the subset I get this:

```
# Create subplots for the first two components
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

cfset = ax[0].contourf(xx, yy, f, cmap='coolwarm')
ax[0].imshow(np.rot90(f), cmap='coolwarm', extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
cset0 = ax[0].contour(xx, yy, f, colors='k')
ax[0].set_xlabel('X')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Y')
ax[0].set_title('All data')

cfset = ax[1].contourf(xx, yy, f0, cmap='coolwarm')
ax[1].imshow(np.rot90(f0), cmap='coolwarm', extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
cset = ax[1].contour(xx, yy, f0, cset0.levels, colors='k')
ax[1].set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
ax[1].set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
ax[1].set_xlabel('X')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Y')
ax[1].set_title('Subset')

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

I need the subset to have the same color scheme, and ideally, similar contour levels as it appears in the full set.

Comment: Is the integral of both the left and right datasets equal to 1? (It should be if they're both proper densities). How do the ranges of the datasets compare? It might not be such a bad idea for the scales to be renormalized.

Comment: @Reinderien Not really, all I did to obtain the densities is np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, xx.shape). The problem is that, for the subset, it calculates the densities independently of the original data set, and I need it to be normalized but I'm not sure how to do that.
The second set is a subset of the left one. the left plot *should* be a bi-modality, and my subset is trying to obtain the top portion of the bi-modality. However, it shouldn't appear so dense as in the original plot is very low-populated.